# Min-height for responsive adsense unit

Tags: html, css, adsense

I've got a responsive ad unit on my page and for some reason, it has a height of 60px, while i really need it to be 90px and switch to 300x250 when screen gets smaller. Is there any way to control that?

p.s.
it's pretty standard adsense code

```
<div classs="adunit">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Pmember Resp1 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-****"
     data-ad-slot="*****"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
```

css for it is

```
.adunit {max-width:730px}
```

I've tried

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block;min-height:90px"
```

and i've tried

```
.adunit {min-height:90px}
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant codes of that element.

Comment: Please provide that adsense div as well as the parent div on your question. Replace the adsense code with some dummy text if you don't want to share the link.

Answer (score 3):

You are using *smart sizing* (`data-ad-format` attribute) and you can control the general shape...

> ... by changing the value of data-ad-format to one of these values:
>   "rectangle", "vertical", "horizontal" or any combination of these
>   separated by a comma, e.g., "rectangle, horizontal".

Create a responsive ad unit / Specify a general shape
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893

If you want the full control over the height, you'll need to remove `data-ad-format` and to use `@media` queries:

```
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
@media (min-width:500px) { .adslot_1 { width: 300px; height: 250px; } }
@media (min-width:800px) { .adslot_1 { min-width: 300px; max-width: 970px; width:100%; height: 90px } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
  style="display:inline-block;"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
  data-ad-slot="5678"></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

Above snippet is a combination of "*Specify an expandable width and a fixed height*" and "*Specify an exact size per screen width*" from the [page I linked](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893).

If you want to put this unit on top of the page, then I think you'll want to leave `.adslot_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }` in code as I suggested, because:

> **Is placing a 300x250 ad unit on top of a high-end mobile optimized
>   page considered a policy violation?**
>
> Yes, this would be considered a policy violation as it falls under our
>   ad placement policies for site layout that pushes content below the
>   fold. This implementation would take up too much space on a mobile
>   optimized site's first view screen with ads and provides a poor
>   experience to users. Always try to think of the users experience on
>   your site - this will help ensure that users continue to visit.

AdSense policy FAQs / Part 3: Mobile-related
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3394713?hl=en#3

Maybe you'll want to see tiny tutorial I wrote about `@media` queries with AdSense:

Why we shouldn't use @media queries on AdSense ins tag
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/TiihLH_gMnw

Comment: Funny how that is/was a policy violation, but when I had `data-ad-format` set to auto, it was automatically creating a 250px ad unit and pushing content down on mobile. Didn't know how to turn it off until I saw your post since it wasn't obeying any CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your **height issue** is in your question title itself.

Just give a unique class or id name to that element like this:

```
<div class="someUnit">
    <!--some codes-->
</div>
```

And add this to your css:

```
.someUnit {
    min-height: 90px;
}
```

---

And for the **smaller screens issue**, use `media queries` like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .someUnit {
         width: 300px;
        height: 250px;
    }
}
```

**N.B.** Replace `480px` with the proper screen width you want the bigger dimensions on.

Comment: yeah. i've tried that. Google sets the height regardless of parent div height unless it's limited

Comment: Please provide that adsense div as well as the parent div on your question. Replace the adsense code with some dummy text if you don't want to share the link.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data-ad-format="auto"` and set `dimensions` in style attribute.